# How to make UIButton play corresponding audio clip from selection in UITable?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uibutton, avfoundation, viewcontroller

I have two Scenes in my storyboard, the first simply contains a UItable populated by an array of words. When a cell is selected my app segues to the second scene that contains a label (which is given content of its corresponding "wordTitle", see below) and a button. Inside my Supporting files folder I have one audio file representing each entry in my UITable. I have a custom class called Word that has a "wordTitle" property. I created a number of Word objects in my viewcontroller.

```
words = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//custom Word class object
Word * wrd = [[Word alloc]] init];
wrd.wordTitle = @"One";
[words addObject:wrd];

wrd = [[Word alloc]] init];
wrd.wordTitle = @"two";
[words addObject:wrd];

// and so on.
```

The label in the second scene is being updated correctly every time I select a cell in the UITable. How do I go about setting the button so that when it is pressed in the second scene the corresponding audio file is played?

Answer (score 0):

This entire thing is much easier now using the new AVFoundation AVAudioEngine. Basically you will create an audio engine and an AVAudioPlayerNode and load an audiofile into the player and play it.

```
    var error: NSError?
    let engine = AVAudioEngine()
    let playerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()

//set up the audiofile
    var audioFileUrl : NSURL?
    var audioFile : AVAudioFile?
    var audioFormat :AVAudioFormat?
```

attach the audiplayernode to the engine

```
let mainMixer = engine.main

MixerNode
        engine.attachNode(playerNode)
 //wire it up
    engine.connect(playerNode, to: mainMixer, format: audioFormat)

//Gentlemen start your engine
    engine.startAndReturnError(&error)
```

normally to load an audio file into the player you would use something like:

```
 func loadAudioFileInotPlayer(){
         audioFileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:"/somepath/filename")
         audioFile = AVAudioFile(forReading: audioFileUrl, commonFormat: .PCMFormatFloat32, interleaved: true, error: &error)
        audioFormat = audioFile!.processingFormat

    }

func Play (){
    //Load the audio file into the player node
    playerNode.scheduleFile(audioFile, atTime: nil, completionHandler: nil)

    playerNode.play()
    println("Play was pressed")
}
```

You would need to create a string for the path in the audioFileUrl that points to the filename that you want for that specific file to load. I hope this helps.